# Como o NodeJS gerencia package.json em sub-pastas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, packages, módulo-ecmascript, modularização

Como o NodeJS gerencia packages.json em sub-pastas?

Você tem sua aplicação normal mas tem sub-módulos que você quer que tenha suas próprias dependências, como o Node gerencia isto? Ele cria outro `node_modules` e coloca todos os arquivos novamente dentro dessa sub-pasta?

(Suponha que seja um erro de arquitetura mas...), na hipotética idéia de que tivessem duas dependências da mesma versão tanto no package de cima quanto nos packages dos subpacotes eles iriam ter a mesma versão replicada tanto no `node_modules` da pasta raíz quanto no `node_modules` das sub-pastas?

Exemplo:

```
└─── MinhaAplicacaoDeExemplo
    └───v1
        │--- package.json
        └─── node_modules
        │    └─── lodash1.0
        │
        │
        └─── sub-pasta-que-tem-os-proprios-modulos
           │--- package.json
           └─── node_modules
                └─── lodash1.0
```

Comment: Ter duas versões do mesmo pacote no `package.json` é uma discussão longa que tem estado ativa na NPM: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na versão 3.0 do NPM eles corrigiram esse problema: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-dupe

Answer (score 1):

Atualmente o npm não permite duas versões do mesmo pacote, visto que no `package.json` os pacotes são gerenciados por nome.

No caso das subpastas, o npm não as gerencia como se fossem submódulos, como o git faz, por exemplo. Tudo que o npm toca está registrado no `package.json`.

Se quiser ter pastas diferentes para módulos que pretende usar como dependência de outro módulo, use a funcionalidade de [`link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) do npm, que permite registrar pastas como se fossem pacotes para serem instalados em outros projetos.